# asp .net 4.0 - web farm/session/long running tasks

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

My questions are two fold -

We have a asp .net Webforms website that lets users authenticate with sites like Facebook, Google, etc. and once authenticated, users are redirected back to our site and does some processing on some data that might take a few minutes to complete. The long running tasks are started on separate threads and users are shown the progress via Ajax calls.

So far it was using InProc session on a single server and everything worked fine. Now we are moving to a web farm and have to move the session to an out of process model and that's my first question. What is the recommended way for storing session out of proc? Or should I not use session at all and use something like memcached to store user generated data that is only valid for that user session? What offers more scalability and performance?

In a web farm environment, as the subsequent requests could be served by any one of the servers, how do you handle long running tasks? For e.g. the task could be started by one server and the next request from the same client/session could come to a different server in the farm. In the single server + InProc model we were using ManualResetEvent to wait (or timeout) and would respond back to the client when the process is done. Should we just look for some shared object to be set in cache/session?

Thanks for any tips/help.